# How app detect the current device's MDM register status

Tags: ios, objective-c, mdm

I am a iOS enterprise developer. I am developing a App about mobile device management(MDM). As known, after device resisted MDM, a config profile is installed from Safari. How can my App detect the profile is installed? Or there is other ways can app detect MDM register status.

Thanks